# How to program the cannon ball to be shot from the tip of the barrel?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm writing a script in C# for the trajectory of a cannon ball. The canon ball is a prefab with a script for its trajectory when shoot from a canon. I can make the canon ball shoot at more or less the correct angle in which the canon barrel is tilted. But when I tried to incorporate gravity, successive canon shooting fail. The first canon ball seem to shoot at the correct angle and follows the law of gravity but can't shoot a second canon ball.

The general of how this works is that we have a canon script that create a canon ball prefab when space key is pressed. The canon script passes to the cannon ball script the rotated angle of the barrel and time in which the space key is pressed. The canon script uses Translate method to translate the canon ball according to the angle parameter and incorporate the gravity mechanism by subtracting from the y-velocity, (Time.time-createdtime)^2*gravity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//This is the script for the cannon
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{   
    int time = 1;
    float minRotation = -90;
    float maxRotation = 0;
    Vector3 currentRotation;
    public Transform fireBall;
    canonTrajectory ct;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public Transform circle;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ct = fireBall.GetComponent<canonTrajectory>();
        currentRotation = transform.parent.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            currentRotation.z -= 5.0f;
            currentRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.z, minRotation, maxRotation);
            transform.parent.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);

        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            currentRotation.z += 5.0f;
            currentRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.z, minRotation, maxRotation);
            transform.parent.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            ct.setCreatedTime(Time.time);
            ct.setRotationAngle(currentRotation.z);
            Transform fireInstance;

            fireInstance = Instantiate(fireBall, new Vector3(transform.parent.position.x, transform.parent.position.y+3.0f, transform.position.z), transform.rotation) as Transform;

            Transform c = Instantiate(circle, fireInstance.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;

            c.SetParent(fireInstance.transform);



        }
    }

}









using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class canonTrajectory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float rotationAngle;
    float createdTime;
    float speed = 150f;
    float gravity = -200.0f;
    public GameObject turkey;
    static int NUM_PARTICLES = 26;
    Vector3[] m_position = new Vector3[NUM_PARTICLES];
    LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public void setCreatedTime(float time)
    {
        createdTime = time;
    }
    public void setRotationAngle(float angle)
    {
        rotationAngle = angle;
    }

    public float GetRotationAngle()
    {
        return rotationAngle;
    }
    void Start()
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        float directionx = Mathf.Cos(-rotationAngle*2.0f*Mathf.PI/360.0f);
        float directiony = Mathf.Sin(-rotationAngle * 2.0f * Mathf.PI / 360.0f);
        Debug.Log(-rotationAngle * 2.0f * Mathf.PI / 360.0f);
        float directionVectorLength = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Pow(directionx, 2) + Mathf.Pow(directiony, 2), (0.5f));

        Debug.Log("created time: "+createdTime);
        transform.Translate(-5 * directionx, 2 * directiony-(Time.time-createdTime)* (Time.time - createdTime) * 2.0f , 0.0f);

        if (transform.position.x < -300)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        if (transform.position.y < -77)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the firing action. As you can see, gravity doesn't work and multiple cannon ball is shot at the same time. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWh1D.png)

Comment: Create an empty gameObject where you want to shoot from as child of your gun, then instanciate at that position

Answer (score 0):

This script *works* only if you presume that the player is oriented along the X axis.
It could be that you rotate the player and that is why the ball rotates.

Also you could get more help if you could produce some video of the issue. Just screen capture a couple of seconds long gif.